plot() error: seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number in Windows and Macos
Could anyone help me to understand why:
xt = as.POSIXct(c("2023-09-03 12:00:00", "2023-09-03 16:01:40"), tz = "Chile/Continental")
plot(xt, c(1, 2), type = "l")

in R triggers the following error:
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
It seems specific to this date and timezone. I have also tried using as.POSIXlt() instead of as.POSIXct() but that does not address the error.
Update: Error seems specific to Windows OS and Macos and does not apply to Ubuntu (see comments).
I was expecting that R could draw a line between these two timestamps and show them on the horizontal axis of a plot. This is a minimal example of project where I plot longer time series.
I have reviewed all stackoverflow posts that discuss the same error but all of them seem specific to certain (tidyverse) R packages. Instead I would like to use base R code to make this work.
 > sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Amsterdam
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.4.1 tools_4.4.1  


Perhaps a bug? E.g. changing the first time to 12:10:00 it will no longer give an error. (You'd need plot(xt, c(1, 2), type = 'l') to get a line graph, btw.)

The error is coming when calling grDevices:::prettyDate(structure(c(1693752620, 1693768280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Chile/Continental")). It does seem to be specific to the time zone. If you try grDevices:::prettyDate(structure(c(1693752620, 1693768280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")) there's not a problem.  Does Chile observe some sort of daylight savings adjustment that might be around these date/times?

^ en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Chile: "Starting in 2016, Chile returned to UTC−04:00 for winter time for 3 months. ... from 2019 onward, it will start on the first Sunday of April and end on the first Sunday of September." Chile switches from UTC-04:00 to UTC-03:00 at the first moment you have described, as they go from winter time to summer time.

Works fine for me. Everything updated? Provide sessionInfo().

@jay.sf sessionInfo() now added and all is up to date.

Ok, the issue seems Windows OS specific, because I am not able to reproduce it in Ubuntu 22.04.

@V.vanHees You're probably right. I'm also running Ubuntu 22.04.

I get the same error using MacOS, so it's not just a Windows thing.

MacOS and Windows both use R's included libraries for timezones, while linux uses the system's, and may be different. See ?timezones.
